¿Cómo puedo solucionar el error al momento de ejecutar el comando de npm install usando la versión de Node 6.17.1?
Descargue un proyecto de GitHub hecho en laravel en donde me pide instalar la versión de Node.js 6.17.1 y luego ejecutar el comando de "npm install", pero cuando lo hago, instalan algunos paquetes pero luego me aparece el siguiente error:
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.22621
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.17.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path C:\laragon\www\inventory\node_modules\.staging\@types\q-367fe7df\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOTDIR
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\laragon\www\inventory\node_modules\.staging\@types\q-367fe7df\package.json'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\laragon\www\inventory\npm-debug.log

El archivo package.json contiene lo siguiente:
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.17",
        "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^1.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "vue": "^2.5.7"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "sweetalert2": "^7.32.4",
        "vue-moment": "^4.0.0",
        "vue-multiselect": "^2.1.4",
        "vuejs-datepicker": "^1.5.4"
    }
}

El mismo problema lo tenían otras personas cuando ejecutaban el npm install, y algunos decían que era por la versión de laravel-mix 1.0, que era una versión que ya no funcionaba.
¿Alguno sabe cuál puede ser la solución?
